# What do the terms mean in cpu usage into Apache Status?

Tags: php, apache, centos, cpu-usage

In apache status page into WHM there is a line showing cpu usage. This line looks like this.

```
CPU Usage: u133.74 s28.94 cu0 cs0 - .0108% CPU load
```

what do the terms (`u,s,cu,cs`) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in a serverfault questions:

`u=user, s=system... cu and cs are the cumulative values of u and s`

Original answer found at:
https://serverfault.com/questions/225913/explain-apache-status

Comment: **u133.74**  is very higher value. Is it appearing in percentage? Its more than 100. Which value is considered as best??

Comment: I belive its seconds since last restart.